# AppStore review of multiple version numbers of the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, app-store, app-store-connect

I currently have my app available on the store with version 1.5.0, and my idea is to release 2.0.0, but in case something goes wrong with that version I would like to run in parallel fallback version of 2.0.1 that is going to replace risky feature with another one more stable. Is there any option to achieve this in parallel? ItunesConnect doesn't allow me to create 2 versions at the same time.

I've found [here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev480217e79) that it's not possible to revert to previous app version once new one is out, so there is only this option of releasing a fallback version right after the first one is out.

Comment: You would have to submit a new version and request expedited review, however I have had apps reviewed in an noir or so normally recently so even that may it be necessary.

Comment: You should also use TestFlight to test your new version prior to release

Comment: I am, but this one is a bit more complex and impossible to test via TestFlight. App uses Firebase dynamic links that redirect to the app store instead of the app on return url for some reason. When clicked from notes app it opens the app, but return url is redirecting to App Store, so we can't know for sure if this is going to work in production in a normal way, or we need to fallback and search for more options.

Comment: How can it be impossible to test via TestFlight? If it is because you are going to make back end changes, how are you going to deal with the fact that not everyone will have 2.0 the instant it is released?